# I am having problems with getting if inside a def in python

Tags: python

I tried  to add it to a def and I have so many problems
the code:

````
num2= 0
def a(e,num1,num2):
    {
        if e == "+":
            print(num1 + num2)
    }
num1 = int(input(""))
e = (input(""))
num2 = int(input(""))
a(e,num1,num2)```
````

Comment: @MichaelO. [oh yeah?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P68018hWwYArJTVNIVEjVQfINwQRRppWXApAUA0mQaCgKDOvRAMkr6CtAFYBlwKBzDSFVAVbWwUlbSWF1JziVAW//LxUsIpaLrAmWwWQ/sy8gtISDSUlTU0uoHIFZD7ITExVqI76/9@QS5vLCAA) :-P

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode damn, I see it for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the curly brackets {} in python, not sure how inputs work as I am still new but your function should look something like this.

```
def a(e,num1,num2):
    if e == "+":
        print(num1 + num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

python has no curly braces, but it is still ensured the function code is separated from the outside.
add whitespaces to the inside (beginning of lines) and of the same length.
you already did that, but delete the brackets and the problem will be fixed...
nope
theres a problem with the input as someone in the comments pointed out (not sure if there really is, but...)but... python is not my native coding language. I learned a little, but only a little.

working code

```
def yourfunction():
  print("look at the spaces before this line")
print("it works")
```

im not sure if it actually works. but im definitely sure about no curly brackets

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Community done. and downloading a py interpreter so i can check this, so i dont look stupid